# Adding a print statement to a loop working in a thread making it run faster

Tags: python, multithreading, qthread

I have this thread. When I add a `print` statement in the `while` loop, it works faster. Otherwise very slow.

```
class PubSub(QRunnable):
   def __init__(self):
       QRunnable.__init__(self)
   def run(self):
       while True:
           message["substep"] = "xyz"
           message["timestamp"] = str(datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
           if message["substep"] == "skip":
               continue
           messageJson = json.dumps(message)
           myAWSIoTMQTTClient.publish(topic, messageJson, 1)
           time.sleep(1)

mqtt_worker = PubSub()
mqtt_pool = QThreadPool().globalInstance()
mqtt_pool.start(mqtt_worker)
```

Why is that and how to resolve it?

**Edit:**
If I replace `continue` with `pass`, it makes the other threads run fater. I don't know why is that and neither do I want to `pass`

Comment: What is precisely fast or slow in this loop? The `sleep()` will slow down the whole loop.

Comment: @prog-fh I mean this thread WITHOUT print statement makes the rest of the threads slow. The GUI hangs. When I add a print statement, the GUI works fine

Comment: I would have thought that this was related to the global-giant-lock in C-Python (and a busy thread always locking/unlocking it), but your `time.sleep(1)` should slow down this thread and let the other ones run. Are you certain the problem arises when `sleep()` is used here?

Comment: No it doesnt have anything to do with `sleep()`. Whether it is present or absent, the issue remains the same. I tested it

Comment: Please create a *complete* example - enough code that someone can run it without modification and see the problem (and no more than that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the order of `time.sleep`. The issue was, since `message["substep"]= "skip"` most of the time, therefore, `time.sleep` wouldn't execute and the thread doesn't get the chance to `sleep`. Therefore it would keep running very fast, without allowing other threads to breath some.

```
class PubSub(QRunnable):
   def __init__(self):
       QRunnable.__init__(self)
   def run(self):
       while True:
           message["substep"] = "xyz"
           message["timestamp"] = str(datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
           time.sleep(1)
           if message["substep"] == "skip":
               continue
           messageJson = json.dumps(message)
           myAWSIoTMQTTClient.publish(self.topic, messageJson, 1)
```

The reason why `print` statement would help other threads to run faster previosuly is because I/O operations are slow and therefore would block this current thread for a while and would allow other threads to continue their work.

Comment: Agreed and probably even sleep(0) would work because all you are doing is giving the scheduler a chance and a hint that this would be a good time to switch to another thread. I would probably put it immediately after the while or at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: @eemz any idea why `pass` would help too? in place of `continue`? However it made the logic wrong, but the GUI worked fine afterwards.

Comment: because "pass" execution would carry on into messageJson, myAWSIoTMQTTClient.publish, _time.sleep()_ whereas "continue" would jump straight back to "while"